# best way to rotate images, divs or list elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css, rotation

so far I was using a jquery plugin .rotate() to rotate my images, but this plugin has still a lot of bugs...

Basically I have some list elements with text and a picture inside each li element... Now I want to rotate each li element randomly in an angle of +- 10 deg...

What is the best script or method to rotate elements? canvars, css3? some easy to handle jquery plugin I dont know?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="test1.png" style="display: inline;">
        <p>blabla</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="test2.png" style="display: inline;">
        <p>blabla</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS to rotate the element and then use a class for it.

Check demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rCr9P/)